# sintaxe if () em uma trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger, condição

Estou tendo dificuldades com a sintaxe do if() no phpmyadmin. 
Tenho que criar um TRIGGER para inserir informações em um log quando o nome de um animal da tabela animais for alterado. Mas está dando erro de sintaxe no if(). Quando eu tiro o if ele funciona. Alguem pode ajudar?

Segue o codigo:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER log_update 
AFTER UPDATE ON animais 
FOR EACH ROW

IF ( OLD.nome_animal <> NEW.nome_animal) THEN

INSERT INTO log_animais(codigo, momento, ocorrencia) VALUES ( OLD.cod_animal, now(), OLD.nome_animal  ) 

END
 $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Quando coloco o BEGIN, END e/ou END IF ele tambem da erro.

Answer (score 1):

Tem um erro nisto que é exatamente no `END`. O `END` é para encerrar o `BEGIN`, se deseja encerrar o `IF` utilize o `END IF` em seu lugar.

De maneira final ficaria assim:

```
CREATE TRIGGER log_update 
AFTER UPDATE ON animais 
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

 IF(OLD.nome_animal <> NEW.nome_animal) THEN

   INSERT 
    INTO log_animais(codigo, momento, ocorrencia) 
     VALUES (OLD.cod_animal, now(), OLD.nome_animal);

 END IF;

END
```

Comment: é isso, eu coloquei assim tambem, e dessa forma tambem da erro nos END. Se colocar o DEMILITER da mais erro ainda. Nao to entendendo mesmo. rs

Comment: @LuanAraujo Qual o erro exato? Testei isto exatamente no MariaDB e funcionou normalmente.

Comment: "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 11"
Finalmente consegui assim: 
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER log_update AFTER UPDATE ON animais 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF(OLD.nome_animal <> NEW.nome_animal) THEN INSERT INTO log_animais (codigo, momento, ocorrencia) VALUES (OLD.cod_animal, now(), OLD.nome_animal);
END IF;
END; $$ ;
DELIMITER ;

O estranho era que ficava aparecendo X vermelho do lado do codigo, como estivesse errado. Mas muito obrigado pela força @Inkeliz !